# Scrape the data through time with API limit in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, data-science

I am trying to scrape the messages from the Nordpool website.

Link to messages: https://umm.nordpoolgroup.com/#/messages?publicationDate=all&eventDate=nextweek

API: https://developers.nordpoolgroup.com/docs/umm-api-messages-search

Unfortunately, API only allows to scrape 1000 messages at once. However, I want to include all messages for Nuclear in SE from 01.01.2012 till today (definitely more than 1000 messages).

Here is the code I have to scrape last 1000 messages.

```
url <- "https://ummapi.nordpoolgroup.com/messages?fuelTypes=14&IncludeOutdated=true&publicationStopDate=2019-10-11&areas=10Y1001A1001A46L&limit=1000"

data <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(url))
```

I was thinking if it is possible to write a loop that can go through all dates, however, could not solve this issue so far. Maybe you have any ideas?

Thanks a lot,

Katya

UPD. Thanks to @dswdsyd I managed to change the code and get the correct result. Now it looks like:

```
url <- "https://ummapi.nordpoolgroup.com/messages?fuelTypes=14&IncludeOutdated=true&areas=10Y1001A1001A46L&limit=1000&skip="
    skiprec <- 0
    max <- 0
    df1 <- data.frame()

repeat {
  url <- paste0("https://ummapi.nordpoolgroup.com/messages?fuelTypes=14&IncludeOutdated=true&areas=10Y1001A1001A46L&limit=1000&skip=",skiprec)
  req <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(url, flatten = TRUE))
  max <- req$total[1]
  df1 <- rbind.fill(df1,req)
  skiprec <- skiprec + 1000
  if(skiprec >= max) {
    break
  }
  else {
    rm(req)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the API documentation, there seems to be a provision to skip/jump ahead X records, so basically you access the next 1000 records by setting the skip value to equal 2000.

Hence, you can probably write a for loop to loop through until the day is done, i.e. something like this:

```
library(jsonlite)

url <- "https://ummapi.nordpoolgroup.com/messages?fuelTypes=14&IncludeOutdated=true&publicationStopDate=2019-10-11&areas=10Y1001A1001A46L&limit=1000&skip="
max <- 0
skiprec <- 0
df1 <- c()

repeat {
  url <- paste0(url,skiprec)
  req <- fromJSON(url)

  max <- req$total

  article <- req$items$reasonCode
  df1 <- append(df1,article)

  if(skiprec >= max) {
    break
  }
  else {
    skiprec <- skiprec + 1000
  }

}
```

Hope this helps!